# Web service missing in labview

Tags: labview

I intend to create a labview web application from scratch. Unlike step 2  mentioned here,
 http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361K01/lvhowto/build_web_service/,
The web service under mycomputer in a new project is missing. I dont know if I am missing a package or something
Help me out here guys[image]

The version of Labview is 2013 and it's a student edition
I have attached a screen shot

Cheers
Gokul

Comment: I would try asking this on the NI forums, and/or upgrading to the latest version of the student edition if that's possible for you?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your LabVIEW version is not professional:

Have a look: http://www.ni.com/labview/buy/

Comment: Your link shows that either the Full or Professional version of LabVIEW should have web service capability - it's just the Base version that doesn't. But at https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-30610 - which seems to date from 2013 - it says that the Student Edition has the same functionality as the Full version.

Comment: Student edition has its own variations. Have a look: https://www.ni.com/labviewse/compare/

Comment: But [Web services FAQ](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/7747/en/) states that student edition supports web services